# Control-alt-delete RDP from RDP

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to remote desktop into one windows server and then from there remote desktop into another windows server (don't ask...). I know that you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd> to act as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> in remote desktop but this only affects my first RDP connection, how do I do this for the second one?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below worked for me when attempted Keyboard Keys Highlighted.<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> on Box2  from Box1

1. RDP to your Box2 from Box1
2. Open On-Screen Keyboard on Box2. eg on Windows 2016 server it would be under
   Open C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessibility\On-Screen Keyboard
3. When On-Screen Keyboard comes on Box2, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd> of "Box1 keyboard" and using mouse click on "Box2's On-Screen Keyboard" DEL button.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an RDP within another RDP, Ctrl+Alt+End may not work as expected -- it sometimes could bring up the Task Manager / Change Password screen for the outer RDP.

Instead, to bring up the Task Manager / Change Password screen for the inner RDP :

Bring up the on-screen keyboard (Start > Run, type osk.exe)

Hold Ctrl+Alt on the top-level machine and click Del on the OSK.

This should work for any number of nested RDPs.